# Review audits should not include deleted migrated posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audit

I was just trying to procrastinate a bit of work, so I figured I'll check the review queue. This came up:

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/571044

It is a closing vote review of a question that was migrated almost three months ago, and was deleted almost two months ago. The only option is to skip this review, and that's fine. But it shouldn't be included in the first place if there is no actionable way to audit my response.

Shouldn't there be some check before pushing something as a review audit, that *some* action can even be made on the review?

Comment: see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315033/reopen-queue-audit-failed-because-the-question-had-been-migrated/322389#322389

Comment: So... I shouldn't blame caching this time. Let me refresh and see if this is still the right thing to do. *Hits F5 a few times.* Hmm, no change. I guess I should blame caching.

Comment: Yeah, audits don't get invalidated once they're created. The issue with that audit was that it was created 1 day after the question was already migrated (because the post was cached as a known good post).

Comment: Ah. I see. Thanks. Do questions with [status-completed] get autobumped by Community? If so, feel free to post this as an answer, and I'll accept it. If not, then never mind.

Comment: yeah, `status-*` removes them from our internal bug lists

Comment: That's not what I asked, though. Upvoted questions without an answer get periodically bumped by the Community user. Does it hold for questions with status-* tags on meta sites also?

Comment: @m0sa: How does this relate to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/26042/deleted-migrated-question-in-review-queue then?